# xcode 6 symbol navigator shows each class twice

Tags: swift, xcode6

Looking at my project in the symbol navigator view, I noticed each class listed twice. They are identical, but the code runs fine, what is going on?

Comment: XCode (with Swift) still has a lot of hick-ups. Restarting helps in most cases. Eventually try `rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"` in between.

Comment: Thanks thomas, will do.

Answer (score 1):

Even if Xcode 6 isn't in Beta anymore, there are still a lot of issues(Editor stops working etc.). In most cases these errors can be resolved by simply restarting Xcode.

If that doesn't help you, try to Clean your project: `Product->Clean`. Also you could clean Xcode manually by deleting all files inside `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`