# Xcode symbol navigator not showing app symbols

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

Probably this is another bug in Xcode (saw this one: [xcode 6 symbol navigator shows each class twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549848/xcode-6-symbol-navigator-shows-each-class-twice) but it did not help).

In my Xcode I see symbols only for a .h file I created for `iCal` and none of the symbols for my main app. Is there some hidden option where I can switch what to see in the symbol navigator?

My broken navigator looks like this:

[image]

(Shows only info from iCal.h)

While in the same session another project looks ok:

[image]

(I added Swift/Obj-C to reach the main Xcode user group, though this is not related to any of the languages)

Comment: Good screen shots! What if you now click the middle icon the bottom? Do you see the vast world of framework symbols? - Also, what if you quit Xcode and empty the caches, as I suggest here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073 ? Sometimes indexing gets "wedged" and you need to slap Xcode on the side of the head.

Comment: When clicking the middle button I see a lot, but _none_ of my app symbols. And as written above I already cleared also DerivedData.

Comment: Cleaning the cache is something I do on an hourly basis. :-(

Comment: Try clicking the `►` in front of the class name; It should drop down showing the symbols.

Comment: @ili The issue is that there are only symbols from my Obj-C h file `CalAppDelegate` and the included `iCal.h` but none of my main app.

Comment: I find that if I turn a Swift project into a hybrid project the symbol navigator doesn't work properly until I quit Xcode and clean the caches and launch it again. That's why I suggested it; you seem to have a hybrid project.

Comment: @matt I need just one Obj-C source since Swift does not work smoothly with `ScriptingBridge`. I created a temp project but there it did show the mix of my Swift sources and my Obj-C included stuff. Most likely this is an XCode bug. I'll submit it to radar.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I quit Xcode. I cleaned my derived data directory (you can find it by going to 'File' -> 'Project Setting'). After that I restarted Xcode. It re-indexed all the files and now the symbol navigator is working as expected. Hope these steps work for you too.

Comment: Well, cleaning derived data and cache was something I did on an hourly basis for quite a while. Now I'm using XCode 7 and forgot even about that issue (probably because I simply got used to a bug that I was not expecting to get fixed). Thanks anyway.